# How to prove the point is within a zonotope?

Tags: convex-analysis, analytic-geometry

Sorry, I don't know how to describe the diagram precisely. But all the sides looking parallel are indeed parallel and of the same length.

I want to prove the red point (characterized by the three bold vectors are the same) is within the boundary. A brute-force method is to express it as a convex combination of some vertices. But I feel that there should be a more straightforward geometric way.

[image]